# Branching Strategy: Branch from Branch

Tags: git, azure, branch

Quick question in terms of branching in a specific scenario.

I have my main Master branch, I created a branch from that to build my new functionality (branch 1), I then raise a Pull Request to have it reviewed, but, the code has not yet been reviewed and is preventing me from building the next set of functionality.

What I done is create a new branch (branch 2) from the branch that's waiting to be reviewed (branch 1), then once branch 1 is reviewed and signed off, it will be merged to Master and then I can simply raise a PR for branch 2 which will then be merged to Master also once signed off.

Is there a better approach, i.e. a best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems legit. You could even create your second PR as soon as it's ready, maybe with a comment to warn about the other PR to be reviewed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with this approach.
You should also `git rebase master` right before creating the pull request, just in case the code review of branch1 caused some fixes you don't know about, or in case some branch3 has been created by another teammate and merged to master while you've been working on branch2.
In those cases, not rebasing will cause the pull request to add changes of removing the changes made by others.